# Static methods and Singleton in PHP

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, exception, singleton

I have the next class:

```
class MyClass {
    private $_instance = null;
    private function __clone() {}
    private function __construct() {}
    public static function instance()
    {
        if (is_null(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new self;
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public static function methodOne() {}
    public static function methodTwo() {}
    public static function methodThree() {}
    public static function methodFour() {}
}
```

And I have a lot of methods `method...()`. But this methods can be executable only if `instance` is not null. How can I throw an exception if `instance` is null?

I need to use only `static` methods. I can not use non-static. I want to use the next design:

```
MyClass::instance();
MyClass::methodOne(); // If no instance throws an Exception.
```

Comment: `throw new Exception('message here')` :)

Comment: Why would you want to do that explicitly? If you try to use `$instance` you will get a fatal error in any case. Also, it seems you are terribly abusing singleton here (which is already terrible to begin with). What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I need to use static methods.

Comment: @stereofrog: oops, sorry for stealing you answer (I blame my slow writing).

Comment: You need to use static methods and you also need to make them behave like instance methods? Something is not right.

Comment: @garvey: if you need it, you could use Robik's answer but that is really repetitive. Why would you need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not make the methods static, only keep `instance()` static.

It will lead to:

```
$m = MyClass::instance();
$m->methodOne();
```

Comment: I know it. By I want to create the next design: MyClass::instance(); MyClass:methodTwo();

Comment: +1 You don't need static methods. It's kinda the point of having a singleton. You can access it everywhere staticaly.

Comment: More over, why do you need a singleton if you only use static methods? Static methods are class functions and therefore do not require an instance of the class.